# g++ using a object file in external directory

Tags: c++, g++, raspberry-pi, header-files, object-files

**Context:**

I am current learning c/c++ compiling on my raspberry pi b+ model (started last week), but having trouble using a header file inside a object file.

---

**File locations:**

main.cpp      - ~/src/c++/projects/web_server

http_socket.o - ~/src/c++/web

---

**g++ output for `g++ -o webserver ~/src/c++/web/http_socket.o -std=c++0x main.cpp`**

main.cpp:3:25: fatal error: http_socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include "http_socket.h"

int main() { return 0; }
```

**http_socket.cpp**

```
#include "http_socket.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

http_responce::http_responce(string status_Code, string date, string server, string content_Type, string content_Length) {
Status_Code = status_Code;
Date = date;
Server = server;
Content_Type = content_Type;
Content_Length = content_Length;
}
```

**http_socket.h**

```
#ifndef HTTP_SOCKET_H
#define HTTP_SOCKET_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class http_responce 
{
    public:
    string Status_Code;
    string Date;
    string Server;
    string Content_Type;
    string Content_Length;

    http_responce(string status_Code, string date, string server, string content_Type, string content_Length);

    private:

    protected:
};

#endif
```

---

**Addition note:**

I am very new to this language and accustomed to using an IDE, so please forgive me if it is something very trivial that I have missed.

Comment: Try adding `-I~/src/c++/web` to your `g++` command line.

Comment: Sorry typo... you need a space between `-I` and `~` or the shell won't expand it, i.e. `-I ~/src/c++/web`.  Alternatively, just replace `~` with the absolute path to your home directory, or use `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you are telling `g++` where to find the `http_socket.o` object file, you need to help it out and tell it where it can find the `http_socket.h` header file you are including from `main.cpp`.  You do this by passing the `-I` preprocessor option to `g++` with the directory that contains `http_socket.h`.

Assuming `http_socket.h` is in the same folder as `http_socket.o`, you would use `-I ~/src/c++/web` so that your full command line for building `webserver` would be the following:

`g++ -I ~/src/c++/web -o webserver ~/src/c++/web/http_socket.o -std=c++0x main.cpp`

From the GCC [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> `-I` *`dir`*
>
> Add the directory *dir* to the list of directories to be searched for header files. Directories named by `-I` are searched before the standard system include directories. If the directory *dir* is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated . If *dir* begins with `=`, then the `=` will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see `--sysroot` and `-isysroot`.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so it's needs to see the header file, I assumed that the object file I made contained it. I've been going through TheNewBoston's c++ tutorial on youtube. I remember him saying that the cpp file is compiled in machine code and the header file left as plain text for users to view, though somehow that didn't come to mind this time. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the http_socket.h file in the directory you are trying to compile. This should be the easiest solution.
Basically what's happening is that the compiler can't find the header file you specified.

Reference :

[What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: Thats is indeed a quick fix, but I prefer to keep the files in their specific directory to avoid having many dupes.